# problems with SSL certificates in local environment

Tags: node.js, next.js, ssl-certificate, localhost

Good morning, I have an application made with next.js and node/express (it is an application to respond to technical supports) and it must be able to upload and download attachments.

The problem is that for a few weeks now I have not been able to download the files even though they are in the public folder because the connection is not https.

In next.js I modified my package.json adding to "dev" --experimental-https (I understand that this creates a certificate with mkcert) and the front now runs on https but with the back I cannot, if I use the same certificates as next I create myself in the front, the back appears as a certificate but when I want to make a query I receive **::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID** and if I generate a certificate with openssl, although it runs in https it tells me that the certificate is invalid and when I make the query from the front I receive **:: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID** .

Could you guide me how can I solve this? It has to run locally because it is an app for internal use.

Thank you so much

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.